# use EtsyStaggeredGridView library on my project but didn't work?

Tags: android, staggered-gridview, staggeredgridlayout

I use EtsyStaggeredGridView library on my project when I get from the tutorial.

But I do not know where the error lies.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you defined the field as a `StaggeredGridActivity`

Comment: Also, please see their Github... `##Notice - Deprecated - 09-2015`